# De Morgan's Laws proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

My only problem with this proof is that they seem to be assuming that $(A \cup B)'$ is nonempty (similar idea for $A' \cap B')$. Is that because this holds trivially if $(A \cup B)'$ is empty? In other words, $A \cup B = U$ where $U$ is the universal set.

Comment: You know, the more I look at this proof, the more I think it's circular (which _would_ make sense if this is indeed a _law_ or _axiom_--meaning it cannot be proved, it must be taken as true).  For instance (1) $x \not\in A \cup B$ implies $x \not\in A \wedge x \not\in B$ seems to be using the conclusion as the justification for the premise.  It seems to me that the actual _formal_ proof is Wikipedia's _[informal proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Informal_proof)_! (D'Morgan _can_ be proved in propositional logic through a truth table)

Comment: @Jared Let's delete our comments.

Comment: Age is an issue of mind over matter. If you don't mind, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually not strictly necessary to suppose that $(A \cup B)' \neq \emptyset$ because of a rule of inference called "ex falso sequitur quodlibet", meaning "from falsity, anything follows" (I believe this name may come from the Scholastics), which asserts that anything may be proved from a contradiction (the idea is that if we have lowered our standards of truth to the point that we've let something false be true, then we kind of have to let anything be true).

So, if $(A \cup B)' = \emptyset$ then supposing $x \in (A \cup B)'$ gives a contradiction since $(A \cup B)'$ has no elements, thus $x \in A' \cap B'$ by ex falso.

Comment: -1 I think that this is wrong. although you're right about ex falso, I don't think it applies here.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Why would ex falso not apply here? You want to show $(A \cup B)' \subset A' \cap B'$. So, you suppose $x \in (A \cup B)'$. Then you split by cases on the emptyness of $(A \cup B)'$. If $(A \cup B)'$ is non-empty, you follow the argument given in the textbook. If $(A \cup B)'$ is empty then $x \notin (A \cup B)'$, giving a contradiction thus, by ex falso, $x \in A' \cap B'$. I could verify this argument using a mechanized proof assistant and post the code if you'd like.

Comment: @JacobGross No, the proof formally states $\exists x: x \in (A \cup B)'$.  However, when $(A \cup B)' = \emptyset$ there is no such $x$ and thus anything that follows that _requires_ such an $x$ to exist cannot logically follow.  Before you say that $x\in A'$ you _must_ assume the $x$ exists, but it _doesn't_ when $(A \cup B)' = \emptyset$.

Comment: No, @Jared, the proof step is $\forall x : [x\in (A\cup B)' \to x\notin (A\cup B)]$.  Its not asserting that such an element exists; its saying that any element in the complement of the union, is not in the union.

Comment: The proof does not state $\exists x, x \in (A \cup B)'$, it supposes this for the sake of a conditional proof -- but the non-emptyness of $(A \cup B)'$ is not a hypothesis of the theorem and it does not need to be.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I disagree, although we may be splitting hairs.  The proof says "Let $x$...--this cannot possibly have the same semantic meaning of $\forall x: x \in (A\cup B)' \rightarrow x \not\in (A \cup B)$.  Indeed, the way you stated it, if $(A \cup B)' = \emptyset$ then for all $x$, the hypothesis is false and thus the statement is true (but _not_ the specific conclusion).

Comment: Ex falso applies in conditional statements. It says that $P\Rightarrow Q$ is true when $P$ is false for every $P$. But there are no implications here.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Yes there is, the implication is $x \in (A \cup B)' \Rightarrow x \in A' \cap B'$

Comment: You're right. I understand, I missed how the cases were working. This is correct. If you edit the post I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that this proof is assuming that $(A\cap B)'$ is nonempty. Luckily, we can quite easily check that it holds in that case, as it means that there are no elements not in both $A$ and $B$, and so $A'\cap B'=\emptyset$. Likewise for the other direction, if $A'\cap B'=\emptyset$ then there are no elements that are in neither $A$ nor $B$, so $(A\cup B)'=\emptyset$. The second part of the theorem is likewise easy to show.

Comment: I think you mean "no elements not in $A$ and $B$."

Comment: @user19405892 fixed

Answer (score 1):

When it says "Let $x\in (A\cup B)'...\;$", this is a way of saying "For all $x$, if $x\in  (A\cup B)'...$" Similarly for "Suppose $x\in A'\cap B'...$"  in the second part. Without altering the logic the proof can be re-worded as

(1)....$\forall x\;(\; [x\in (A\cup B)']\implies$ $ [x\not \in A\cup B]\implies$ $ [x\not \in A\land x\not \in B]\implies$ $ [x\in A'\land x\in B']\implies$ $ [x\in A'\cap B']\;).$

(2)....$\forall x\;(\;[x\in A'\cap B']\implies$  $[x\in A'\land x\in B']\implies$ $ [x\not \in A\land x\not \in B]\implies$ $ [x\not \in A\cup B]\implies$ $ [x\in (A\cup B)']\;).$

(3)....From ( 1)and (2) we have $$\forall x\;(\;[x\in (A\cup B)]\implies [x\in A'\cap B']\;),$$ $$ \forall x\;(\;[x\in A'\cap B']\implies [x\in (A\cup B)']\;).$$ Therefore $\forall x\;(\;[x\in (A\cup B)']\iff [x\in A'\cap B']\;).$ Therefore $(A\cup B)'=A'\cap B'.$

The proof is about twice as long as necessary.Notice that (2) is (1) backwards. That is, every "implies" in (1) and in (2) can be replaced by "iff".

At no time is it assumed that anything actually does belong to any of the sets that are mentioned.